Python Airflow - how can I extract the results from a PythonOperator?
I have a dag that calls on a function that returns a PythonOperator. I want to get the results of this task, so that I can pass it to another task. Any ideas if this is possible?
Here is roughly what my code looks like:
    def DAG(self):

        args = {
            "owner": "airflow",
            "depends_on_past": False,
            "end_date": None,  # runs forever
            "retries": self.retries,
            "retry_delay": self.retry_delay,
            "start_date": self.start_date,
        }
        with DAG(dag_name, default_args=args, schedule_interval=dag_cron,...) as dag:
            self.parsing_tasks()
            if self.factset_cbbo_us:
                all_us_equity_mics = grab_all_mic()   <----- here is where a PythonOperator is returned

                generate_external_sensor_tasks(all_us_equity_mics)
            return dag

    def grab_all_mic():
        something = PythonOperator(
            task_id="blah_blah",
            python_callable=blah_blah_blah,
            op_args=("some_task", self.parsing_day_delta),
            retries=10,
            on_failure_callback=on_exhausted_retries_failure_callback,
        )
        return something

Do let me know if more information is needed :)
I found a similar question but I couldn't quite get what I needed from the responses: Python Airflow - Return result from PythonOperator

Which version of Airflow are you using ? Airflow tasks do not generally output results, and you should instead try to create a workflow that doesn't need passing task results. You can use XCOM or if you're using Airflow 2 you can also use Task Flow.

A task is supposed to be an atomic operations and usually doesn't need to communicate information with other tasks.

Got it, I thought as much. It didn't feel right extracting the results from a PythonOperator. Thanks for the feedback

What we usually do, is we output the result of the previous tasks to a unique deterministic path (depending on the date for example), and then we read this output in the next task only by providing the path.

Option 1
You can use XCOM to pass any serialized Python object, although it is not recommended for medium/large-sized data since it is stored in the Airflow database.
def use_mic_values(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    mics = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='grab_all_mic_task')
    process_mics(mics)

With this example, you can access the data generated by grab_all_mic with xcom_pull
Option 2 - Larger data volumes
I propose a second option for when your data is larger.

In this approach, your grab_all_mic task would generate the data and save it in a distributed cloud storage service like AWS S3 or Google Cloud Platform's Cloud Storage. This function should return the path where the data has been saved.
In the data processing task, you will need to retrieve the path from XCOM and access the cloud storage service so that this data can be accessible from any task.
Although this type of storage service is cheap, it would be a good idea to schedule a cleanup task once the data is no longer needed.
With this example, you can access the data generated by grab_all_mic regardless of its size.

